# Graphic Tic Tac Toe in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, graphics, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a program for my Visual Basic class that is supposed to create a game of Tic-Tac-Toe to be played by one human and the computer.

Here are the instructions:

1. Create two views (one as a GUI view and the other as a text view using the console).
2. Use two controllers (one where the user clicks on the GUI and the other where the user uses the numbers 1-9 on the keyboard.
3. Use one model.
4. Use a module to keep the state of the game in a 2D array. All logic applied to the model will be in the module (for example, only the module is allowed to change the 2D array).
5. The grid is to be drawn graphically (not using labels, buttons, etc)

Here are some of the questions I'm having so far:

1. I know how to create a GUI view, but have no idea how to use the console to create a text view?
2. Not quite sure how the 2D array is supposed to work in this situation (I've declared it as follows, but not sure where to go from there).

   ```
   Module Module1
       Dim game(2, 2) As String
   End Module
   ```
3. I've drawn part of the grid, but having trouble doing the rest. I need one more vertical line and one more horizontal line, and it needs to be divided correctly. Here's what I have for the drawing so far:

   ```
   Private Sub Form1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
       Dim blackBrush As New Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Black)
       Dim xBase As Integer = 50
       Dim yBase As Integer = 10
       Dim width As Integer = 200

       e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Green, xBase, 10, 200, 200)
       Dim third As Integer = yBase + width / 3
       e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, xBase, third, xBase + width, third)
       e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 100, 5, 100, 220)
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am giving you half of the solution but in C# :D**

*It shouldn't be very hard for you to convert it to VB, it is exactly the same framework.*

*Hopefully, you'll understand the mechanics and not simply dump my code, it's really simple in fact.*

(drop a PictureBox onto your form first)

**The grid :**

Here I'm drawing squares but that should be pretty easy to draw lines instead.

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.Paint += pictureBox1_Paint;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int columns = 3;
        int rows = 3;
        Graphics graphics = e.Graphics;
        graphics.Clear(Color.White);
        RectangleF bounds = graphics.VisibleClipBounds;
        var cellWidth = (int)((bounds.Width - 1) / columns);
        var cellHeight = (int)((bounds.Height - 1) / rows);

        for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
            {
                graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(x * cellWidth, y * cellHeight, cellWidth, cellHeight));
            }
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

**Here's a very simple board :**

```
internal class TicTacToe
{
    public TicTacToe()
    {
        Grid = new Piece[3, 3];
    }

    public Piece[,] Grid { get; private set; }

    public void SetPiece(int x, int y, Piece value)
    {
        if (x < 0 || x > 2) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("x");
        if (y < 0 || y > 2) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("y");

        Piece piece = Grid[y, x];
        if (piece == Piece.None)
        {
            Grid[y, x] = value;
        }
    }

    public Piece GetPiece(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x < 0 || x > 2) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("x");
        if (y < 0 || y > 2) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("y");

        return Grid[y, x];
    }
}

internal enum Piece
{
    None = 0,
    Cross = 1,
    Circle = 2
}
```

You could return a `boolean` or throw an exception, I just silently update the game in my example.

**What's left for you ?**

- Find if someone has won, this can be tricky to implement :D ***really***
- Draw in console mode

I'll give you some pseudo code for the console :

```
Do
  Get user input
  Update the grid
  Check if someone wins
  Clear console
  Draw current game or game over screen
Loop until ESC (quit) is pressed
```

For drawing the grid in console basically it's the code above except that dimensions are much smaller and pixels are characters instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Console(v=vs.110).aspx

As I said, converting it should be trivial since MSDN docs do provide VB as well as C# examples in every of their docs pages.

Good luck !

Comment: Thanks for the help, should be interesting since I've never used C# before haha, but I'll try.

Comment: I'd rather help you a little than not, but giving you the whole solution would not be helpful to you IMO. I would have loved to use VB but it's been many years I've stopped using it :D